# Creating a python callback for a C function from a DLL with a char buffer.

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am trying to create a python wrapper for a C DLL. The C DLL uses a callbacks to "send" messages via UDP from the DLL.

What I expected to happen was that python code would load the DLL library and the two functions. Then it would register the call back with the DLL using the `RegisterCallbackSendMessage` function. The pointer to the callback would be stored in memory in the DLL memory space. Then the python code would call the SendWhoIs DLL function. This function would create a buffer and use the SendMessage function pointer to send the message from the DLL to the python code.

The issue I am having is that the `message` parameter in the `SendMessage` function in python doesn't know how to interpreter a `void *` and I can not pass this buffer to `sock.sendto` function.

I get the following error.

```
sock.sendto(message, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

My question is: How do I convert a c_void_p to a byte array that sock.sendto can accept.?

I have tried to reduce my code as much as possible and still make it understandable.

This is my C code

```
// C DLL code 
// 

#define DllExport extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )

typedef uint16_t(*FPCallbackSendMessage)(const uint8_t * message, const uint32_t length);
FPCallbackSendMessage g_CallbackSendMessage;

DllExport bool RegisterCallbackSendMessage(uint16_t(*p_CallbackSendMessage)(const uint8_t * message, const uint32_t length)) {
    g_CallbackSendMessage = p_CallbackSendMessage ; 
    return true;
}

void SendWhoIs(unsigned int dd) {
    printf("dd=%d", dd); 
    char buffer[500];
    g_CallbackSendMessage( buffer, 500 ); 
}
```

And this is my python code

```
# Python code 
# =================
print("Start") 

customDLL = cdll.LoadLibrary ("customeDLL.dll")

def SendMessage( message, length ):
    print("SendMessage...") 
    UDP_IP = "192.168.1.1"
    UDP_PORT = 47808
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.sendto(message, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    return True 

print("Registering Callback SendMessage...") 
SendMessageFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_bool, c_void_p, c_uint)
SendMessage_func = SendMessageFUNC( SendMessage )

RegisterCallbackSendMessage = customDLL.RegisterCallbackSendMessage
RegisterCallbackSendMessage.argtypes = [ SendMessageFUNC ]
RegisterCallbackSendMessage( SendMessage_func ) 

print("Do message...") 
SendWhoIs = BACnetStackDLL.SendWhoIs
SendWhoIs.argtypes = [c_uint]

SendWhoIs( 47 )

print("End")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

in the python SendMessage function I figured out a way to convert the c_void_p to a byte array.

```
# convert the pointer to a buffer. 
buffer = c_char * length 
messageToSend = buffer.from_address(message)
```